# django annotate queryset based on attribute

Tags: django, django-models

is there a way to do the following in *one* Django query?

```
MyModel.filter(attr=a).values('attr','fields','of','interest').annotate(count=Count('id'))
MyModel.filter(attr=b).values('attr','fields','of','interest').annotate(count=Count('id'))
```

edit:
I need separate counts for a and b. `MyModel.filter(attr__in=(a,b))...` or `MyModel.filter(Q(attr=a)|Q(attr=b))...` won't work I guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your MyModel class may have an order_by value set to order on something not in ('attr','fields','of','interest').  Try removing the ordering or ordering by one or more of the fields of interest.

```
MyModel.objects.values('attr','fields','of','interest'
        ).annotate(count=Count('id')).order_by()
```